# How to have multiple selectable options property listed in Properties Window? - .NET

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, properties

I have a UserControl with a property called "Type". This can have any combination of three values, say

One 
Two
Three

How do I do this? This is more like the anchor property for controls in WinForms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[Flags]
enum Foo { One=1, Two=2, Three=4 }
```

You use an enum annotaed with the Flag attribute. You than can say something like

```
aUserControlInstance.Type = Foo.One | Foo.Three;
```

to set multiple flags, i.e. you use the bitwise or operator to combine them.